# Showing $\lambda^n$ is an eigenvalue of $A^n$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

Prove:If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $\lambda^n$ is an eigenvalue of $A^n$.

I basically wanted to understand what's missing/incorrect in my proof. Please help me out. Many thanks.

Let $A$ be an nxn matrix with $x$ a nonzero vector and $\lambda$ a scalar s.t. 
$Ax = \lambda x$, where $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue and $x$ is the eigenvector w.r.t $\lambda$.

Now, post-multiplying both sides by $x^-1$, we have
$$Ax.x^{-1} = λxx^{-1} $$
$$A = \lambda I\tag{1}$$, where $I$ is the identity matrix.

$(1)$ implies, to maintain the equality, if $A$ is pre-multiplied by $A$, then $\lambda$ needs to be premultiplied by $\lambda$. Thus, 
$$A^2 = \lambda^{2}I \tag{2}$$

It follows from $(2)$ that $$A^n = \lambda^nI$$

QED

Please comment on issues/problems with this proof. Will really appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by the inverse of a vector!?!?

Comment: Suppose A has a Jordan Canonical form J. Its clear that $\lambda$ is on the diagonal of J because its an eigenvalue. $\A^n$ has a jordan form of $J^n$, with $\lambda ^n$ as a diagonal element. This means its also an eigenvalue.

Answer (score 3):

The flaw is in $x^{-1}.$ what is $x^{-1}$?

For example, for matrix $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

what would your $x^{-1}$ be? $x$ is a vector in this case.

I am enclosing a proof that $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue for $A^2$.

Let $x$ be an eigenvector of $A$.

$$A^2x=A(Ax)=A(\lambda x)=\lambda Ax = \lambda (\lambda x) = \lambda^2 x$$

Hopefully you can see the proof for general $n$.

Comment: Tip: use induction